# Center Google Map on Select Option AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm trying to center map based on selection in drop down select option box.  I've tried several examples, but I have yet to get the map to center to the new latitude and longitude coordinates.

I would like to make work using the existing code without starting over with another example.

Latest example I am trying is below in the code with `centerMap()` function.

Please help.
 Thanks!

```js
var sites = [{
    name: "ABC",
    FiftyPlus: "0.72",
    GAs: "0",
    AccPerOpp: "20.09",
    AutoPay: "0.44",
    WTR: "100",
    ISE: "Bert Bingham",
    lat: "29.9792183",
    lng: "-90.22268919999999"
  },
  {
    name: "AJAX",
    FiftyPlus: "0.81",
    GAs: "0",
    AccPerOpp: "18.7",
    AutoPay: "0.13",
    WTR: "100",
    ISE: "Bert Bingham",
    lat: "30.0032515",
    lng: "-90.22060119999999"
  },
  {
    name: "CBS",
    FiftyPlus: "0.8",
    GAs: "0",
    AccPerOpp: "16.99",
    AutoPay: "0.23",
    WTR: "100",
    ISE: "Bing Bingle",
    lat: "43.9703011",
    lng: "-90.08290799999999"
  },
  {
    name: "Turner",
    FiftyPlus: "0.78",
    GAs: "0",
    AccPerOpp: "17.68",
    AutoPay: "0.23",
    WTR: "100",
    ISE: "Bing Bingle",
    lat: "43.004759",
    lng: "-90.17053299999999"
  },
];
```

//Angular App Module and Controller

```js
angular.module('mapsApp', [])
  .controller('MapCtrl', function($scope) {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.340803, -89.4855946),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var mapOptions1 = {
      zoom: 9,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.3186154, -85.8286258),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    function centerMap() {

      if (document.getElementById("ISEs").value === 'Bert Bingle') {
        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions1);
      }
    }

    $scope.markers = [];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    /*var icon = {
            url: "image/store.svg", // url
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25), // scaled size
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
        };

    */
    var createMarker = function(info) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.lng),
        title: info.name,
        icon: {
          url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png"
        }
      });
      marker.content = '<div class="iw-ISE">' + info.ISE + '</div>' +
        '<div class="iw-labels">' + "GAs: " + info.GAs + '</div>' +
        '<div class="iw-labels">' + "Auto Pay: " + info.AutoPay + '</div>' +
        '<div class="iw-labels">' + "AccPerOpp:$ " + info.AccPerOpp + '</div>' +
        '<div class="iw-labels">' + "Fifty Plus: " + info.FiftyPlus + '</div>' +
        '<div class="iw-labels">' + "WTR: " + info.WTR + '</div>' +
        '<p>' + info.address + '</p>'

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent('<h2 class ="title">' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
        infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
      });
      $scope.markers.push(marker);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
      createMarker(sites[i]);
    }

    $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker) {
      e.preventDefault();
      google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    }

    $scope.clearMarkers = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.markers.length; i++) {
        $scope.markers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      $scope.markers.length = 0;
    }

    $scope.filterMarkers = function() {
      //1.select filtered cities
      var filteredISE;
      var ISEName = $scope.data.singleSelect;
      if (ISEName == '0') {
        filteredISE = sites;
      } else {
        filteredISE = sites.filter(function(c) {
          if (c.ISE == ISEName)
            return c;
        });
      }
      //2.update markers on map
      $scope.clearMarkers();
      for (i = 0; i < filteredISE.length; i++) {
        createMarker(filteredISE[i]);
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Map</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <div align="center" class="input-w">
      <div class="gulf">Gulf States</div>
      <fieldset>
        <label>ISE: </label>
        <select id="ISEs" class="dropdown" name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-change="filterMarkers()" ng-change="centerMap()">
          <option value="0">all</option>
          <option id="1" value="Bert Bingham">Bert Bingham</option>
          <option id="2" value="Bing Bingle">Bert Bingle</option>
        </select><br><br>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <a href="#" ng-click="openInfoWindow($event, marker)">{{marker.title}}</a>
  </div>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAz-1j7m4EfcSFL9o_L4BV7OPyGWNlzpbI&sensor=false" onerror="googleError()"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Regardless, why are you checking the DOM (`document.getElementById("ISEs").value ==='Bert Bingle'`) instead of checking the model (`data.singleSelect`)?

Comment: The `<select>` element has two `ng-change` directives. That won't work with the HTML parser. On chrome, the second `ng-change` is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues in your code:

1. When you call to controller's function, you need to define it on the controller's scope. 
   So instead of just declare the function

   ```
   function centerMap() {
   ```

   Declare it on the controller

   ```
   $scope.centerMap = function () {
   ```
2. Like @georgeawg said, you have two `ng-change` directives on the `select` tag, you can combine them like this:

   ```
   ng-change="centerMap();filterMarkers();"
   ```
3. You're checking (in the `if`, it the value is `Bert Bingle` but it's never that's value because the (attribute) `value` of the option `Bert Bingle` is `Bing Bingl`. Also, you should check the scope and not the DOM so the right check is

   ```
   if ($scope.data.singleSelect === 'Bing Bingle') {
   ```
4. And finally, you don't need to create a new map in order to change the map's setting, there is an api for that [`setOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.setOptions).

   So, instead of calling

   ```
   $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions1);
   ```

   Call this way

   ```
   $scope.map.setOptions(mapOptions1);
   ```

Working example

https://jsbin.com/cuqigaz/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I made the changes suggested and still not working.  When I checked the working example, the map doesn't pan to the new location when i select the drop down.  ?

Comment: jsbin does problems some times, and not all my changes saved :| Now the snippet should work. But anyway, if you followed all my changes, it should works. Try to create the **minimal** working snippet (you can duplicate my jsbin) which reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry I got it to work in my code.  Thank you! This is really great!

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck!